# Have an ImageView with a default height, change height when an image is put into it

Tags: android, image, dynamic, imageview, height

So I am making an app that holds multiple user-chosen pictures. I have default ImageViews with pre-set heights of 300dp. I want this height to change to wrap_content once an image has been placed into the ImageView. The only way I know to do this is to remove the image from the layout and then re-add it with a new LayoutParams, but this messes up the order of the other views in my layout. Can I change the height without removing it?

Essentially:

```
LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
LinearLayout.LayoutParams mTestImgParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                (int) Math.ceil(scale * 300)
        );
final ImageView createdView = new ImageView(this);
mainLayout.addView(createdView, mTestImgParams);

//onLongClick listener, get picture, set the picture into the imageview, etc.
```

I somehow want to change the

```
(int) Math.ceil(scale*300)
```

to

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
```

without removing and re-adding the ImageView, and only after the image has been placed. Help please.

Comment: in xml you can use  android:minHeight=300dp and then use a height of wrap content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to get the current layout params and change it.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) createdView.getLayoutParams();
params.height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
createdView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: Worked great, Thanks!